# How do I resolve the saga has been cancelled error?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using redux saga to handle my async operations. I have a call to the actionCreator on component Mount. But the saga is being called multiple times. And as a result the api call is being called continuously. How do I resolve this?

Please find my code below.

```
import { takeLatest, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import MyOrdersApi from 'yoda-interfaces/lib/MyOrders/MyOrders';
import * as MyOrdersActionTypes from '../actionTypes/MyOrdersActionTypes';

export function* myOrdersSaga(action){
   try {
     const myOrders = yield call(MyOrdersApi.getMyOrders);
     yield put({ type: MyOrdersActionTypes.GET_MY_ORDERS, myOrders })
   }
   catch(error){
     yield put({ type: MyOrdersActionTypes.GET_MY_ORDERS_ERROR, error })
   }

}

export default function* watchMyOrdersSaga() {
   yield takeLatest(MyOrdersActionTypes.GET_MY_ORDERS, myOrdersSaga);
}
```

Comment: The saga looks fine. The problem maybe is when you're calling it while mounting of component.

Comment: We have the same problem. How do you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was dispatching the same action from the myOrdersSaga that my watchMyOrdersSaga is listening for which made it recursively call the api. The correct code should have been

```
import { takeLatest, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import MyOrdersApi from 'yoda-interfaces/lib/MyOrders/MyOrders';
import * as MyOrdersActionTypes from '../actionTypes/MyOrdersActionTypes';

export function* myOrdersSaga(action){
   try {
     const myOrders = yield call(MyOrdersApi.getMyOrders);
     yield put({ type: MyOrdersActionTypes.GET_MY_ORDERS_SUCCESS, myOrders })
   }
   catch(error){
     yield put({ type: MyOrdersActionTypes.GET_MY_ORDERS_ERROR, error })
   }

}

export default function* watchMyOrdersSaga() {
   yield takeLatest(MyOrdersActionTypes.GET_MY_ORDERS, myOrdersSaga);
}
```